# Difference between writing JS/HTML code in .HTML file and shiny

Tags: javascript, shiny

When I write the below code in .html and execute, it works fine

```html
<h1>Change the HTML content</h1>
<h2 id="hcontent">Hello Manu</h2> 
<h3>Welcome</h3>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('hcontent').innerHTML='Hello Mr. Manu'">Click here</button>
```

But, when I write the same in shiny, it does not.
Can anyone help me on how to execute it?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
# source("myfun.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
tags$head(HTML("<h1> Chnge the html content </h1>
<h2 id = 'hcontent'> Hello Vinay </h2> 
<h3> Welcome </h3>
<button type = 'button' onclick='document.getElementById('hcontent').innerHTML='Hello Mr Vinay'>Click here </button>"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a problem statement. Please see [ask] and revise to be more specific.

Comment: Protip: Single quotes for JavaScript, double for HTML. This eliminates nearly all such problems and minimizes the need to escape quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem were the quotes. Try the following

```
HTML("<h1>Change the HTML content</h1>
<h2 id=\"hcontent\">Hello Vinay</h2> 
<h3>Welcome</h3>
<button type=\"button\" onclick='document.getElementById(\"hcontent\").innerHTML=\"Hello Mr. Vinay\"'>Click here</button>")
)
```

Don't use `tags$head()` because that will place the code in the <head> tag